# Core Data Base Methods

Tags: ios

How to save data using core data in iOS app?

I have created the sample code but not working!..

```
#pragma mark - Core Data Saving support

- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `ManagedObject` with `EntityName` in which you want to store data. Follow this code:

Use your EntityName and keys in which you want to update values.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newDevice setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.versionTextField.text forKey:@"version"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.companyTextField.text forKey:@"company"];

    NSError *err = nil;

    if (![context save:&err])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[err localizedDescription]);
    }
```